# opencv imshow() function has buttons now?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Python 2.7 with OpenCV 3.1.0 to display and interact with images. When I run my script in debug mode in pycharm everything works fine.

However, when I run my script from the terminal the cv.imshow() window has buttons and mouse events which conflict with my pre-programmed ones.

This is the tool-bar I get  (which is blank in debug mode):

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove this?
I couldn't find any details in the opencv imshow() documentations

Comment: It may be worth reading the documentation of highGUI, specifically the notes for [`namedWindow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow).

Comment: that's the Qt gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create a [named window](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b) with the flag `cv2.GUI_NORMAL` which will remove those buttons and give you an old opencv style window. If you want the toolbar, just use `cv2.GUI_EXPANDED` flag. This is something to do with Qt support. It is weird that you get different with pycharm

Something like:

```
cv2.namedWindow('input', cv2.GUI_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('input', img)
```

Comment: Ah Thank you!
For some reason it didn't recognise cv2.GUI_NORMAL,
so I just used the integer value (16) instead.

cv2.namedWindow('input', 16)

Comment: Not sure if it's related but I also get different waitkey() returns if I am debugging in Pycharm or running on the terminal

Comment: @saulgold It may be that the variable is call different in the newest version. not sure what do you mean with different return, but maybe is this problem that it has some bits turn on in some and you have to do a bitwise and with 255.

Comment: I think it's `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` however that doesn't remove the buttons for me

Comment: @Sdra If you go the link in the post you will see "CV_GUI_NORMAL or CV_GUI_EXPANDED" to disable/enable Qt. Important thing to note: the window title (in this case 'input') has to be the same in imshow and in namedWindow. I would have to see the code to actually tell you what could be wrong. Feel free to add a new question with the code you have tried to get a better answer :)

Comment: @api55, thanks! btw in 4.1.1 it's now `WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL`